# Shell script: unexpected token ´if"

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Disclaimer: I am just a guy who googled most of his knowledge when it was needed and there might be no cohesion at all. Sorry for this in advance.

I am writing a small script on my *Ubuntu 18.04* server that should run a loop for encoding raw DVR files into easy to handle mp4. This "hard" part works fine already, I am just trying to get a clean script to let it run by the full hour. Unfortunately for whatever reason bash doesn't accept my if statement.

I tried `dos2unix`, semicolons, spacing, tabbing, intendation before and after the if statement but nothing worked. I scavenged almost all google results and stackoverflow-posts but nothing worked. I checked for hidden characters that could break the script. Still the error.

In the following script the XXX are placeholders for private stuff. Those lines already work.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in $(find /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXX/* -name "*.h264");
    if [ -z "$file" ]
            then 
            echo "No new h264-files found. Exiting."; break
    fi

    do
            echo "H264-files found. Calling ffmpeg for conversion to mp4."
            ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 26 -an -sn "${file/h264/mp4}"
            echo "Ffmpeg is finished."
            #rm "$file" disabled until scripts works perfectly and is callable from plesk.
    echo "All new files converted. Refreshing XXXXXcloud files."
    sudo -u XXXX php /var/www/vhosts/XXXXX
    echo "Script done."
    done
```

I keep getting the following:

```
    ffmpeg_transcode_h264tomp4.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
    ffmpeg_transcode_h264tomp4.sh: line 3: `if [ -z "$file" ]'
```

Comment: The `if` statement has to come *after* the `do` keyword of the loop.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: (BTW, part of why I advise putting the `do` on the same line as the `for`, with a semicolon between them, is to avoid just this kind of error).

Comment: ...that said, `for file in $(find ...)` is inherently buggy and shouldn't be used anyhow. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for why *not*, and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (especially the "Complex Actions" and "Actions In Bulk" sections) for what to do instead.

Comment: Another point -- if there are no files, the loop just won't run at all, so your `if` will never be true.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**`ifne`** util](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) and some advice from [*Charles Duffy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550501/shell-script-unexpected-token-%C2%B4if/56553570?noredirect=1#comment99689181_56553570), this should meet the spec:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/XXXXXX/* -name "*.h264" -print0 |
ifne -n echo "No new h264-files found. Exiting." |
while IFS= read -r -d ''  file ; do
    # ... more code goes here...
done
```

Comment: Less buggy to put a `-print0` on the end of the `find`, and make it `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do`; that way filenames with literal backslashes or newlines, or starting or ending with whitespace, are handled correctly.

Comment: I would also suggest `${file%.h264}.mp4`; right now, you're changing the *first* instance of "h264" in the name to "mp4", which may not be the same as the last instance. (Think of `My Video [h264].h264` as a sample case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks, see revised answer.  For what boils down to a novice loop structure question it's now a more a minimal treatment.

Comment: Will the if ever fire? If there's no file, the read should fail, so the loop body won't execute at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, D'oh!  With *STDIN* `find` the files would always exist -- I'd been thinking of it as though *STDIN* was a pre-existing text file.

Comment: Even then, that file would need to have an empty line rather than just being 0-byte for the loop to ever run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for the corrective comments.  Using the *moreutils* `ifne` command seems to do the trick.  See revised answer.